# Global $root event in vue never arrives

Tags: vue.js

I have a dynamically instantiated vue component which should communicate with the root vue instance via an event. The component (a dialog form) issues the event with `this.$root.$emit()` and the root listens with `this.$root.$on()` and no event arrives. When I debug I see two different instances of `this.$root` which are not the same:

[image: 2 different $roots - wtf?]

What am I doing wrong?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGoPmj

```
// Define component
const StepForm = Vue.extend({
    methods: {
        save() {
            console.log("sending event to ", this.$root)
            this.$root.$emit('stepSave');
        }
    }
});
// Dynamically create component
let frm = document.createElement('div');
frm.setAttribute('id', 'myForm');
document.getElementById('root').appendChild(frm);
let dialog = new StepForm().$mount('#myForm');;

new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('stepSave', ()=>{
      // This never arrives!
      console.log("Got the event!")
    });
    console.log('I am the root', this.$root)
  }
});

function doIt() {
  dialog.save()
}
```

UPDATE: SOLUTION: TLDR: Basically you have to create your component after your root vue instance and [pass that instance to your constructor](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXbqgz?editors=1010).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the parent when the component is created. Otherwise, the `$root` will be equal to the component itself:

```
dialog = new StepForm({
  parent: root
}).$mount('#myForm');
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/stdob__/qcusdr67/ ]

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my CodePen to show how this works:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eXbqgz